# Node.js date.getDate() doesn't return the correct date after change date hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I need to increment hours to a date, but I can't get the correct date after change the hours. For example:

Change the current date

```
let x = new Date(); // 2018-05-30T00:17:04.888Z
x.setHours(x.getHours() + 24); // 2018-05-31T00:17:04.888Z
```

Great! Now the date should be 2018-05-31, right?
But if I try to do the following:

```
x.getDate();
```

It still returns old date: 2018-05-30 and the same happens for `x.getHours()`

Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Is due to timezone offset. The first set of strings you show are UTC values. getDate() will offset UTC value by amount of the timezone offset on machine it is run on

Comment: actually your code is working as you expected, I don't see the issue with that

Comment: Try [`.getUTCDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yeah, that works. The same works for getUTCHours(), getUTCMinutes().... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine.

```
var date = new Date()
date
>Wed May 30 2018 03:26:19 GMT+0000 (UTC)
date.setHours( (date.getHours() + 23) )
>1527726379425
date
>Thu May 31 2018 00:26:19 GMT+0000 (UTC)
date.getDate()
>31
```